# Create variables in a dataframe in R after comparing one by one with another dataframe and with specific name

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with two dataframes in R and I am trying to build new variables after comparing each variable with a dataframe in order to bring a specific value. My dataframes are `DF` and `key` and they look like these (I add the `dput` version in the final part):

```
DF

   ID V1    V2     V3 V4 V5
1 001  Y Zone1 Level0 M1  T
2 002  N Zone2 Level1 M2  O
3 003  N Zone3 Level0 M3 NR
4 004  Y    NR Level0 M4  O
5 005 NR    NR Level0 M4  O
6 006  Y    NR Level1 M4  T
7 007  Y Zone3 Level1 M1  T
8 008  N Zone2 Level1 M1  T
9 009 NR Zone2 Level0 M1  T
```

`DF` has and ID variable and five variables. The other `key` has the next form:

```
key
     Name Value
1       Y    15
2       N    20
3   Zone1    34
4   Zone2     1
5   Zone3     2
6  Level0     9
7  Level1     8
8      M1     4
9      M2     5
10     M3     6
11     M4     8
12     M5     9
13      T     2
14      O     5
```

This dataframe has two variables `Name` and `Value`. So, I want to compare each of the variables in `DF` (`V1,V2,V3,V4,V5`) with `Name` variable from `key` in order to create new variables that save the values of `Value` after their respective comparison. The new variables must have the next name structure: `VI_Name.of.variable.in.DF_M`, for that reason I have build this code:

```
DF$VI_V1_M=key[match(DF$V1,key$Name),"Value"]
DF$VI_V2_M=key[match(DF$V2,key$Name),"Value"]
DF$VI_V3_M=key[match(DF$V3,key$Name),"Value"]
DF$VI_V4_M=key[match(DF$V4,key$Name),"Value"]
DF$VI_V5_M=key[match(DF$V5,key$Name),"Value"]
```

With these lines, I compare each variable in `DF` with `Name` in `key` to bring `Value`, but I don't know how to create a for structure or a function with apply in order to build the required variables because the number of variables in `DF` can increase. I would like to get something like this:

```
   ID V1    V2     V3 V4 V5 VI_V1_M VI_V2_M VI_V3_M VI_V4_M VI_V5_M
1 001  Y Zone1 Level0 M1  T      15      34       9       4       2
2 002  N Zone2 Level1 M2  O      20       1       8       5       5
3 003  N Zone3 Level0 M3 NR      20       2       9       6      NA
4 004  Y    NR Level0 M4  O      15      NA       9       8       5
5 005 NR    NR Level0 M4  O      NA      NA       9       8       5
6 006  Y    NR Level1 M4  T      15      NA       8       8       2
7 007  Y Zone3 Level1 M1  T      15       2       8       4       2
8 008  N Zone2 Level1 M1  T      20       1       8       4       2
9 009 NR Zone2 Level0 M1  T      NA       1       9       4       2
```

Where the results of comparing each variables are saved in the new variables. I am looking for a solution to reduce the number of my lines because in case of 100 variables in `DF` I would have to write 100 lines of code. The `dput()` version of `DF` and `key` is the next:

```
DF<-structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", 
"007", "008", "009"), V1 = c("Y", "N", "N", "Y", "NR", "Y", "Y", 
"N", "NR"), V2 = c("Zone1", "Zone2", "Zone3", "NR", "NR", "NR", 
"Zone3", "Zone2", "Zone2"), V3 = c("Level0", "Level1", "Level0", 
"Level0", "Level0", "Level1", "Level1", "Level1", "Level0"), 
    V4 = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M4", "M4", "M1", "M1", "M1"
    ), V5 = c("T", "O", "NR", "O", "O", "T", "T", "T", "T")), .Names = c("ID", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

key<-structure(list(Name = c("Y", "N", "Zone1", "Zone2", "Zone3", 
"Level0", "Level1", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "T", "O"), 
    Value = c(15, 20, 34, 1, 2, 9, 8, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 2, 5)), .Names = c("Name", 
"Value"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could tackle this as a "reshape-merge-reshape-merge" problem, although there may be a simpler approach.

If you reshaped `DF` to a long format, you could merge this by `Name` with `key` to get all your values in one dataset.  Then you could remove the `Name` variable from the dataset, change the values `V1`-`V5` (now in a column) to match your naming structure, and then reshape the dataset back to a wide format with the former column `Value` as the column values.  One more merge with the original `DF` gets it into the final format you wanted.  It seems like there will be a way to do thsi with less steps, but I haven't thought of anything yet.

I used package **tidyr** for reshaping and **dplyr** for manipulation.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
    gather(Variable, Name, V1:V5) %>% # Put DF in long format
    inner_join(key, by = "Name") %>% # Join with "key" dataset
    select(-Name) %>% # Remove "Name" now so doesn't interfere with spread()
    mutate(Variable = paste("VI", Variable, "M", sep = "_")) %>% # Make names for columns
    spread(Variable, Value) %>% # Put dataset back into wide format
    inner_join(DF, ., by = "ID") # Join with original DF

   ID V1    V2     V3 V4 V5 VI_V1_M VI_V2_M VI_V3_M VI_V4_M VI_V5_M
1 001  Y Zone1 Level0 M1  T      15      34       9       4       2
2 002  N Zone2 Level1 M2  O      20       1       8       5       5
3 003  N Zone3 Level0 M3 NR      20       2       9       6      NA
4 004  Y    NR Level0 M4  O      15      NA       9       8       5
5 005 NR    NR Level0 M4  O      NA      NA       9       8       5
6 006  Y    NR Level1 M4  T      15      NA       8       8       2
7 007  Y Zone3 Level1 M1  T      15       2       8       4       2
8 008  N Zone2 Level1 M1  T      20       1       8       4       2
9 009 NR Zone2 Level0 M1  T      NA       1       9       4       2
```